# How to use injectLazy() delegate from Injekt library with generics?

Tags: kotlin, kohesive-injekt

I have a following class Hierarchy

```
interface Presenter

abstract class MvpFragment<P: Presenter> : Fragment() {
    val presenter by injectLazy<P>() // error: Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
}
```

Is there any way to use the `injectLazy` delegate with generics? I can pass a `KClass<P>` as a parameter to `MvpFragment`, but I still can't figure out how to use it to inject a `P` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do that. But I had to add two new functions first:

```
fun <T: Any> typeRef(type: KClass<T>) = object : TypeReference<T> {
    override val type = type.java
}

fun <T : Any> injectLazy(type: KClass<T>): Lazy<T> {
    return lazy { Injekt.get(forType = typeRef(type)) }
}
```

and now I can write:

```
abstract class MvpFragment<P : Presenter>(presenterClass: KClass<P>) : Fragment() {
    protected val presenter by injectLazy(type = presenterClass)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Generic Type parameters are erased when compiling Java code. Kotlin provides a feature where inline functions can retain this type information all the way to the run time of the program. That feature is what the `injectLazy<T>` function uses to reify the type parameter.

In your case though, the type parameter `P` comes from the class, so the Kotlin compiler can't reify it, meaning it'll get erased when compiling to Java bytecode. With the type parameter erased, the `injectLazy<T>` function can't be called anymore, because the type information will be missing at run time. This is why the compiler gives you the error.

You will have to pass a `KClass<P>` object to your class and use that to inject dependencies, thereby sorta reifying the type manually.

Comment: Just a small note: reification at compile time gives even more than passing class token at runtime: http://gafter.blogspot.ru/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html?m=1 For example, Jackson module for Kotlin uses this.

Comment: Yeah, I understand about verification and erasure. But I don't understand where exactly should I pass `KClass<P>` for injection to work in my case

Comment: I think you can just call `injectLazy(clazz)`, but I'm not 100% certain